# Sort by interger and then smalldatetime in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sorting

Hi am trying to sort by an integer and then a smalldatetime.

The results should look like below

```
Name | int | SmallDateTime
bob  |  0  | 29/06/2014
bob  |  0  | 28/06/2014
Ste  |  0  | 30/05/2014
mike |  1  | 29/05/2014
```

But i get

```
Name | int | SmallDateTime
Ste  |  0  | 30/05/2014
bob  |  0  | 29/06/2014
bob  |  0  | 28/06/2014
mike |  1  | 29/05/2014
```

So its sorting by integer correctly but then it sorts the small date time by day instead of date.

the code i am using is below

```
@SortBy varchar(50)
as
begin
set nocount on;
begin

Select Name 
       ,integer
       ,SmallDateTime
From Table 
Where Name != Null
CASE WHEN @SortBy = 'Available' Then LetAgreed END ASC, CreatedDate  desc
end
```

Any help would be great

Comment: Are you using mysql or sql server? They are not the same thing.

Comment: You're storing your dates as text, aren't you? Stop doing that.

Comment: @podiluska more likely storing by char or varchar. But yes, that seems to be the issue. I wonder if he really has a column named integer and one named SmallDateTime

Comment: No i set column as smalldatetype as i said above. its a sql server

Comment: @t-clausen.dk I was using text in the generic sense, rather than the specific type :)

Comment: Naming the column smalldatetime is NOT the same thing as changing the datatype to smalldatetime. Do yourself a favor and store your dates as dates instead of strings and this kind of painful issue will instantly disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you store your date in SQL as `plain text` or `(varchar / char)`, that's why SQL Server will think `30` is newer than `29` (in descending).

What you need to do is, change the last part of your code to:

```
ORDER BY 
CONVERT(DateTime, CreatedDate,101)
```